# Forward all ports on one IP-address (OpenVPN) to another (local) on Linux

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server installed on 192.168.0.3 as 10.10.10.1. I can  connect from the Internet to my OpenVPN server, the connection is created. Now I have a server on the LAN with IP-address 192.168.0.11 and I'd like to expose it to the VPN als 10.10.10.11. How can I do that? I don't know beforehand what ports will be used by a client.

What I tried is this:

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -d 10.10.10.11 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.11
```

But if I try, on said OpenVPN server itself,

```
telnet 10.10.10.11 80
```

it doesn't work, whereas

```
telnet 192.168.0.11 80
```

connects.

I also activated IP-forwarding on the server, using

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Any hints?? thanks!!

Comment: Why do you want to do NAT? It doesn't appear to be necessary. You should just do normal routing.

Comment: Eh, forgive me, but: how do I do that??

Comment: Done that. You're right, @Michael. Still have issues with the application I want to use though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 10.10.10.11 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.11
```

> But if I try, on said OpenVPN server itself,
>
> ```
> telnet 10.10.10.11 80
> ```

This will not work in principle as you are trying another use case. In case you are going directly from openVPN server the proper chain would be `iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT`, while `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING` will be applied on forwarded traffic (e.g. openvpn clients). In case you would add also this rule it would work (at least partially).

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.11 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.11
```

This approach could work in principle but you need to cover return path - both routing (@192.168.0.11) and firewall rules to allow the traffic (@192.168.0.3/ 10.10.10.1).

## routing

### static route on 192.168.0.11

As this rule would just change the destination IP and not the source the server 192.168.0.11 have to know how to reach the originator of the communication. One of the option would be to add static route on the host 192.168.0.11 for the subnet used for openVPN clients. Then it should work.

```
ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.0.3
```

### pushed configuration to openVPN client(s)

Other option would be not even rewrite the address and simply pass the route to the client. You can push just one IP (192.168.0.11/32):

```
push "route 192.168.0.11 255.255.255.255"
```

or subnet 192.168.0.0/24

```
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

This depends on exact use case you need.

---

Note: In case you are using openVPN 2.3+ on server side you can use openvpn feature instead of  iptables rules (it would be applied on openvpn traffic only):

```
client-nat dnat 10.10.10.11 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.3
```

### firewall

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.11 -d 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Still no dice. I cannot change anything whatsoever in the server 192.168.0.11. I do have a separate client for testing purposes, it does connect to the OpenVPN server correctly (10.10.10.14, gw=10.10.10.13) but it won't open a connection to 192.168.0.11.

Comment: what is pushed routes ? Based on the comment you are using net30 or p2p and not subnet. In that case 10.10.10.11 not necessary have to be routed to VPN tunnel. In that case add to config ```push "route 10.10.10.11 255.255.255.255"``` on server side or ```route 10.10.10.11 255.255.255.255``` on client side.